# PHP bind_param with arrays

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement, bindparam

Is it possible to use [`bind_param()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) with arrays?

For example

```
$stmt->bind_param('iss', Array(101, 'SomeString 1', 'Some string 2'));
// OR
$stmt->bind_param(Array('iss'), Array(101, 'String1', 'String2'));
// OR
$stmt->bind_param(Array( Array('i', 101), Array('s', 'String1'), Array('s', 'String2') ));
```

Is any of these examples possible in PHP (or any other examples)?

Finally I can use my function/class

```
$sql->upload( $table, Array('n;id', 's;username=' . $username, 's;password=' . $password) );
```

Function explination

```
public function upload( String $table , Array $values )

// Where example array could be Array('s;column=someString', 'i;SomeIntegerColumn=10', 'n;SomeID')
/*
    identifier;column=value
    Basically where identifier can be "n", "d", "i" or "s"
    column is the name of the sql column to inset the value to
    value is the string/integer/double to instert in the the column

    Example query with the array mentioned above would be
    "INSERT INTO $table(column, SomeIntegerColumn, SomeID) VALUES(?, ?, NULL)"
*/
```

My project will be out on GitHub really soon :) Thanks a lot!

Comment: I do not believe any of those are possible. But could be wrong. Try them and see?

Comment: Thanks for the help @YourCommonSense, an edit has now been made to explain why i needed this to work with arrays

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If your PHP is not outdated (>= 5.6 namely), just add three dots to the first example,

```
$stmt->bind_param('iss', ...array(101, 'SomeString 1', 'Some string 2'));
```

Comment: I will have a try

Comment: Can I do `$stmt->bind_param($identifiers, ...$array);`

Comment: You just said you'll have a try. Did you?

Comment: Not yet, I'll try now

Comment: Good. It's always good to lay your own hands instead f listening to some unreliable rumor from a stranger.

Comment: That's an interesting and wanted feature. However, this syntax is nowhere in the [official doc](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) ... !

Comment: @ringø no wonder as this syntax has nothing to do with bind_param, as it's an all language feature, argument unpacking operator

Comment: Wow! Learning something every day :-)

Answer (score -1):

Actually you can do even better, if you have an array, {'user' => 'John', 'age' => '20'},  and in your statement you put the parameters with the same name, :name, :age, you can pass this array as a parameter in the execute method, an it will bind perfectly

Comment: @RichardOlsenSandberg why do you think it won't work for PDO?

Comment: Cause `{` and `}` is not Arrays, most likely Objects, but never got them to work as objects either